# Model for Cooperation in a class?

Tags: email, dropbox, postgresql, database-administration, frontend

Assume you have six classes of students with low level of computer skills.
They use Gmail inboxes to store old exam questions, notes and tips. 
Dropbox and Google Drive too, since Gmail inboxes get overflowed easily.

The data includes materials, most materials are text-recognized, from classes 1 to 6, particularly:

- books
- booklets
- handouts given in the class
- presentations of students
- tips for exam

### Problem #1 No will to change mistakes in old materials in Inbox among students

One big problem with Indox style is that no version control.
Sometimes, some mistakes in the materials.
Very little will of students to change the materials, since they should send a new email to inbox about the material and no actual link is made which material is changed.

I see no other way to solve the problem than database model with Good Frontend.
Functions should include:

- Import item to the database with course ID.

### Frontend should include in the browser:

1. - See old material, select it and import a new version of the material with a comment to the mainstream such that you see the version tree
   - do not want to see the Diff between versions in the system because students are using different formats to edit files
2. - Be able to tag files in frontend like Dropbox for pictures
   - Extra Be able to tag pictures like in Dropbox

I have used Postrgresql and know that such a system should not be difficult to be made.

### Some thoughts about simplicity

- No possibility to comment posts in the system, only versions and only possible to upload new file to some tag
- No version control, only tagging, every new file to a tag just increases the number for instance in the tag "Microbiology exam".

**Is there are software that is so simply as described?**

Comment: Your question is not clear.  We also don't do product recomendations.  There is a great number of software solutions to handle documents connected to a course.  I would use one of those solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You are making a basic error if you store shared information which can be changed by multiple users in mailboxes. Information which is shared and changed by multiple users should be one a file-server, a NAS or worst case on Google documents.

If the files are only read by the students, but there is only one person who changes them then consider storing the most recent version on a web page instead.

(Books/booklets/handouts given in the class/presentations of students/tips for exam seems to be stuff which falls in this category).

If you need version control, look at SVN, CSV etc etc. This requires minimal effort to set up the basic commands are easy to teach.  (Ignore complex stuff such as branches, re tagging etc etc. Just use the basics).

Having said that; You could write custom software which does all that. **But why?**

Using off-the-shelf, ready available tools which work well, which have been thoroughly tested and which receive updates is requires less effort to set up and is likely to be more secure. And it might already be present and maintained by the school infrastructure.

Comment: This thing cannot be maintained by school infrastructure. It must be maintained by independent provider. The problem is every one has right to read and change files. I have own server where I can set up the service. I just need to think which service to start such that people can upload and read documents there. The thing should be so simple that students can handle it by browser. Which solutions do you recommend?